# Node Js (Returning null)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, callback, null

I have this function to retrieve a specific user from a mongo db:

```
exports.findById = function(req, res){
    var id = req.params.id;
    db.collection('Users', function(err, collection){
        collection.findOne({'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, function(err, item){
        findPhotoByUserId(item._id, function(photo){
            console.log('photo: ' + photo);
         });            
    });
});
};
```

And this other to get the photo of the user, passing to it the Id of the user:

```
var findPhotoByUserId= function(userId, cb){
    db.collection('Photos', function(err, collection){
        collection.findOne({'userId': userId}, function(err, item){
            if(!err)
                cb(item);
        });
    });
};
```

Problem: the photo item is being null when i call the function "findById". However, if i put the explicit User Id here "collection.findOne({'userId': '522bae4a3ee1be8005000001'}....", the function returns the expected photo item.

Can someone help me about this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i solved my problem!

At this function:

```
var findPhotoByUserId= function(userId, cb){
    db.collection('Photos', function(err, collection){
        collection.findOne({'userId': userId.toString()}, function(err, item){
            if(!err)
                cb(item);
        });
    });
};
```

the 'userId' must be converted do a string.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I got my code to work by using ObjectID in the 'mongodb' library:

```
var ObjectID = require("mongodb").ObjectID;
//more code here
query._id = { $gt: ObjectID(myId) }
```